# 4D array into 2D array and again back to 4D

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have the poses of humans (X, Y, Z values of joints like left elbow, right knee etc) in a video saved in a 4D numpy array.

Example: The poses are saved in the array of shape 3, 103, 25, 2 means: 
3(number of Co-ordinates), 103(number of Frames), 25(Number of Joints), 2(number of persons).

Now I want to change the view angle of this observation. i.e. I want to apply a rotation matrix on all the joint position values.

As of now, I'm

1. iterating through the number of persons
2. converting each person into 2-D array
3. Multiplying the 2D array with a rotation 3x3 matrix
4. Reshaping the rotated 2D array into 3D array
5. Appending the 3D arrays

```
seq = np.random.rand(3, 103, 25, 2)
rot_mat = np.random.rand(3,3)
rotated_seq = np.zeros(seq.shape)
for i in range(seq.shape[3]):  # iterating through person
    person = seq[:, :, :, i]
    joint_values = np.reshape(person, (3, -1))
    rotated_joint_values = np.dot(joint_values.T, rot_mat).T
    rotated_person = np.reshape(rotated_joint_values, person.shape)
    rotated_seq[:, :, :, i] = rotated_person
```

My question is there any way to do this without using the for loop.

Comment: So, it's iterating through `seq.shape[3]`, which is just 2 for the given sample. That's almost as good as vectorized. Is it really `2` for your actual use-case too?

Comment: Yea it is two for the actual use case too. So this is the best way possible?

Comment: Yup, looks good on that.